# Setting min-width - jQuery

Tags: jquery, resize

This works great:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var previewwidth = ($(window).width() - ( $('.aside').width() + $('.results').width() + 110) ) ;
    $(".result-preview").width(previewwidth);
    $("footer").text(previewwidth);

});


$(window).resize(function() {
    var previewwidth = ($(window).width() - ( $('.aside').width() + $('.results').width() + 110) ) ;
    $(".result-preview").width(previewwidth);
    $("footer").text(previewwidth);
});
```

but I'm not sure how to set min and max width, so min-width to 338px and max-width to 500px.

thanks!

Comment: Have you tried doing .css() to max-width and min-width? I.e $('.foo').css('min-width', '338px')

Comment: Is it possible to set the min and max widths in a css file and add the class to the element?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
 $(".result-preview").css({
     "min-width": "338px", 
     "max-width": "500px"
 });
```

Answer (score 10):

Building on @user1113426, due to the way jQuery handles the names, you might need to use camel casing instead of the hyphens.

```
 $(".result-preview").css({
     minWidth: "338px", 
     maxWidth: "500px"
 });
```

Comment: Looking deeper, this may have been resolved in recent releases.

Comment: I still find that I have to use this syntax to get results.